# How would I add a counter corresponding to each hash address of the table?

Tags: c++, hash, linked-list, hashmap, hashtable

I am creating a hashtable using linked list, I have the table working fine, but I need to create a counter for each address in the table.

The program must keep track of the current collision count for each address in the table. To do this, there must be a counter for each address. The addresses are 0 .. tableSize-1. Each time the program inserts an element, it must increment the counter corresponding to the hash address of the element. Similarly, whenever an element is deleted from the table, the counter corresponding to the hash address of the element must be decremented.

How would I go about doing this? Should I add a variable to my list or hashtable to keep track.I dont want to include too much code to make things confusing so I will include snippets from my linkedList.cpp and Hashtable.cpp.

Hashtable.cpp

```
#include "HashTable.h"

// Constructs the empty Hash Table object.
// Array length is set to 13 by default.
HashTable::HashTable( int tableLength )
{
if (tableLength <= 0) tableLength = 13;
array = new LinkedList[ tableLength ];
length = tableLength;
}

// Returns an array location for a given item key.
int HashTable::hash( string itemKey )
{
int hashAddress=0;


for ( int i = 0; i < itemKey.length(); i++ )
   hashAddress= atoi(itemKey.c_str());
return (hashAddress  ) % length;
}

// Adds an item to the Hash Table.
void HashTable::insertItem( Item * newItem )
{
int index = hash( newItem -> key );
array[ index ].insertItem( newItem );
}

// Deletes an Item by key from the Hash Table.
// Returns true if the operation is successful.
bool HashTable::removeItem( string itemKey )
{
int index = hash( itemKey );
return array[ index ].removeItem( itemKey );
}

// Returns an item from the Hash Table by key.
// If the item isn't found, a null pointer is returned.
Item * HashTable::getItemByKey( string itemKey )
{
```

. . .

Linklist.cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

// Constructs the empty linked list object.
// Creates the head node and sets length to zero.
LinkedList::LinkedList()
  {
   head = new Item;
   head -> next = NULL;
   length = 0;
}

// Inserts an item at the end of the list.
void LinkedList::insertItem( Item * newItem )
{
if (!head -> next)
{
    head -> next = newItem;
    length++;
    return;
}
Item * p = head;
Item * q = head;
while (q)
{
    p = q;
    q = p -> next;
}
p -> next = newItem;
newItem -> next = NULL;
length++;
}

// Removes an item from the list by item key.
// Returns true if the operation is successful.
bool LinkedList::removeItem( string itemKey )
{
if (!head -> next) return false;
Item * p = head;
Item * q = head;
while (q)
{
    if (q -> key == itemKey)
    {
        p -> next = q -> next;
        delete q;
        length--;
        return true;
    }
    p = q;
    q = p -> next;
}
return false;
}

// Searches for an item by its key.
// Returns a reference to first match.
// Returns a NULL pointer if no match is found.
Item * LinkedList::getItem( string itemKey )
```

. . .

Comment: I would suggest to read up on [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class HashTable {
    private:
        std::vector<int>* m_collisionsTracker = nullptr;
        ...
}

HashTable::HashTable(int tableLength) {
    ...
    m_collisionsTracker = new std::vector<int>(length);
    std::fill(m_collisionsTracker.begin(), m_collisionsTracker.end(), 0);
}

HashTable::~HashTable() {
    ...
    delete m_collisionsTracker;
}

void HashTable::insertItem(Item * newItem) {
    int index = hash(newItem->key);
    array[index].insertItem(newItem);
    m_collisionsTracker[index] += 1; // If I right understand it's what you need.
}

...

void LinkedList::insertItem(Item* newItem) {
    Item* p = head;
    while (p->next) {
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = newItem;
    newItem->next = nullptr;
    length++;
}
```